# Using wildcards to download a file with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have an url in which there are 6 digits which are changing daily.

**Sample website**:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_160126.csv

This is the part which changes: **`160126`**

I don't know the correct syntax but as a form of pseudo code:

```
$url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets
/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_" + [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+ ".csv"
```

How can I write this string?

To answer the comments, I use it to download that file to a folder, like this:

```
"https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_" + [0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9] +".csv"
$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output  
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: How does you use this string? That will determine how we can call it

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, please see my edit

Comment: @CM2K So you don't actually know what the filename is at any given time? Just that that are 100000 possible different filenames?

Comment: I know the filename should be a date, which is usually the currentDate - 1 day or goes back to Friday if today is Monday. But I don't want to use this logic at all. I simply want to use that website with a placeholder for a 6 digit number before the `.csv`. The file will be there and think it will work

Comment: I asked because I thought that was your thinking. How do you expect it to work? Check 1000's of sites until it gets a hit? Based loosely on today is way better than guessing which `-Uri` does not support.

Comment: @CM2K You can't do what you're describing. You can't supply placeholders to a URL - it just doesn't work that way (unless you have agreed with the website owner to support that specific scenario).

Comment: Is there another page related to that link that would tell you the file name (or whole link) which you could parse out?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Ok, then the way to go would be either: take the most recent file from there and establish that 'recent' by checking the date in that 6 digit string OR simply use the idea from RB. but with some alterations: get-date minus 1 day or if it's a monday get the one from friday. Ideally, would be to get the most recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done. However there are better, more reliable ways to get the same result you are looking for.

I'm with [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039595/3829407). I also found the download page he did. The better way to do this is get the link. Now this is probably not the best way to get the information but it is a start in the right direction.

Note this is slow as hell. Mostly because of `Invoke-WebRequest`

```
$start_time = Get-Date
$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload"
# Browse to the page hosting the csv file.
$request = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/list-MID.en.html"
# Locate the uncompressed CSV file name from the page
$filename = $request.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where-Object{$_.nameProp -match "^ea_csv_\d{6}\.csv$"} | Select -ExpandProperty nameProp
$fileurl = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/$filename"

# Get the file the is hosted today.
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileurl -OutFile "$output\$filename" 
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

The way we find the right file name is with `^ea_csv_\d{6}\.csv$` which matches a name where it is exactly "ea_csv_[6 digits].csv".

Comment: Nice solution, i like the `{$_.nameProp -like "ea_csv_update*csv"}` part

Comment: not the file with the `update` in the name. I was trying to avoid that file like the plague. The uncompressed one above it. Otherwise looks good, will test soon

Comment: changed this part `"ea_csv_update*csv" ` with `"ea_csv_*csv"` But the whole thing returns the html code for the entire page as an error

Comment: Ah. ok Doing that would return more than one link. I can make this work with regex to get what you want.

Comment: this returns: `Invoke-WebRequest : The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload' because it is being used by another process.
At line:10 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileurl -OutFile $output
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`  And i don't have it opened or using it. Do I need some overwrite?

Comment: @CM2K I don't think the error is wrong. I would close PowerShell and reopen. Also make sure the file is deleted ahead of time.

Comment: @CM2K I updated the script. `-OutFile` worked better with a full path.

Comment: Before the last edit, your code worked if I provided in the output path a filename. Testing your last version now. Nevertheless, it works. Thank you for your time

Comment: the last version still doesn't work if I leave it like this: `$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload"` need to put something like `$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload\template.csv"`

Comment: @CM2K hmm... That is essentially what my last update did `"$output\$filename"` .... End of the day the full path needs to be there so what ever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the download page for your filenames by downloading the page or use get-ElementById etc.
I assume, this is the original download  [page](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/list-MID.en.html)

This is your Download URL:

```
    $Url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/list-MID.en.html"
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url
$a = ($page.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table') | ? {$_.classname -eq 'ecb-contentTable'}).textContent
$filename =  $a.Substring($a.IndexOf('ea_csv_'), 17)
$DLURL =  "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/" + $filename
```

Gives:

```
$DLURL
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_160126.csv
```

Complete that with your

```
$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload\" + $filename
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DLURL -OutFile $Output
```

and its done.

Comment: yes, that is the download page. How would you do that? quite new to this

Comment: Thank you Martin, but here there is the same problem as for Matt's solution, will copy paste: "not the file with the update in the name. I was trying to avoid that file like the plague. The uncompressed one above it. Otherwise looks good, will test soon "

Comment: Corrected it from `$DLURL =  "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/" +  $a.Substring($a.IndexOf('ea_csv_update_'), 24)`
to `$DLURL =  "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/" +  $a.Substring($a.IndexOf('ea_csv_'), 17)`

Comment: so, like this? `$Url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/list-MID.en.html"
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url
$a = ($page.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table') | ? {$_.classname -eq 'ecb-contentTable'}).textContent
$DLURL =  "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/" +  $a.Substring($a.IndexOf
$output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DLURL -OutFile $Output`   Doesn't work :(

Comment: Just use first and third Portion of my original answer.
Your $Output misses a filename like $output = "C:\MyFolder\SomeSubFolder\ScriptDownload\download.csv"

(Edited my original answer to reflect changes.)

Answer (score 1):

The 6 digits are the date encoded as YYMMDD, correct? If so, you can generate a URL for the current day with:

```
$currentDay = $(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")
$url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/coll/assets/html/dla/ea_MID/ea_csv_$currentDay.csv"
```

Comment: Almost correct. The data doesn't always gets updated dailly, and then it's the weekend. So, I would rather use something which takes that URL + any 6 digits there + .csv . Also, for today, you don't have today's data. you have yesterday's data and you can guess what happens on monday

Comment: @CM2K How about using a solution like this in a script, schedule it to run with task scheduler and then only run it on weekdays then?

Comment: i don't have access rights for the task scheduler. I would like to incorporate this to my project in SSIS which I have to run myself once a day. But that's another story. I am not looking for any complex solution. Just how to pass that bloody [0-9] 6 times

Comment: @CM2K Sure, that would be lovely, but that can't be done - that's not how HTTP works

Comment: You can try weekday Information of get-date.
Basically you use (get-date).add-days(-1) for tuesday-friday. On Monday you will use (get-date).add-days(-3).